# How can I define #define in my Make files

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

In my c/c++ files, there are multiple #define. As an example:

```
#ifdef LIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBZ
  /* some code */
#ifdef LIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBJPEG
  /* some more code */
```

Can you please tell me how can I modify my Makefile.in so that I have those #define in *ALL* files during compilation?

Thank you.

Comment: consider modifying configure.ac or Makefile.am instead. Makefile.in is not meant for human consumption.

Comment: @unknown: configure.ac will need to set the values somewhere in Makefile.in.  Makefile.in is intended in part for human consumption - unless you are using Automake or something else to generate Makefile.in.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
-DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBZ -DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBJPEG
```

You could pass those in `CPPFLAGS`,

```
CPPFLAGS = -DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBZ -DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBJPEG
```

or make new variable

```
CUSTOMDEFINES = -DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBZ -DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBJPEG
```

and pass it to `CPPFLAGS = -DEXISTINGFLAGS $(CUSTOMDEFINES)`

Those are finally will pass to `gcc/g++ -D...`

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Comment: afaik preprocessor flags should actually go to `CPPFLAGS`

Comment: @s.mark - dang, you hit the nail on the head there....That was what I was trying to figure out....my answer was close but not close enough :)

Comment: cpp refers to C preprocessor, CXX prefix is for C++

Comment: Doing this completely misses the point of using the autotools.  The configure script should determine whether or not to set those variables, not the user.

Answer (score 3):

Add the line below, to your makefile:

```
DEFINES=LIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBZ LIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBJPEG
...
... further on in your makefile on the line where it says ....
...
    $(cc) ($(addprefix -D, $(DEFINES))) .....
...
...
```

This is to serve as an example, you only add another define to the `DEFINES` variable which gets referenced on the line as shown `$(cc) -D$(DEFINES)` in which the make will automatically expand the variable and compile those that are `#ifdef`d.

Thanks to ***R Samuel Klatchko*** for pointing out a small amiss...this is specifically for GNU's make, *you can use addprefix do properly do that ($(addprefix -D, $(DEFINES)))*.

Comment: That will only add -D to the first define (so it will yield `-DLIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBZ LIBVNCSERVER_HAVE_LIBJPEG`).  If you have GNU make, you can use addprefix do properly do that (`$(addprefix -D, $(DEFINES))`).

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: Edited the answer to reflect your comment! Cheers for the heads up! :)

Comment: Normally, $(CC) or ${CC} will have the CC in upper-case, not lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify your Makefile.in.  (and consider using Automake and converting your Makefile.in to a much simpler Makefile.am).  The whole point of those #defines is to let the configure script define them in config.h, and your source files should #include <config.h>.  If you are maintaining the package, you will need to write tests in configure.ac to determine whether or not the system being used has libvncserver installed with jpeg and zlib support.  If you modify Makefile.in to always define them, then you are making the assumption that your code is only being built on machines where those features are available.  If you make that assumption, you should still add checks to configure.ac to confirm it, and have the configure script fail if the dependencies are not met.