# undefined reference to function inside ifdef block

Tags: c++, arduino, c-preprocessor, undefined-reference, esp32

I have the following problem:

I'm writing a collection library for a bunch of sensors to be used with a microcontroller. Meaning I take a lot of libraries for sensors and abstract and simplify them a bit in a unified library for a student project.

I use `#define` structures to figure out which sensors the students want to use and connected.

Example:

```
#define IR_SENSOR_USED
```

In the .h and .cpp files of the library I then use `#ifdef`-`#endif` pairs to define and declare the functions for the given sensor as well as include the given libraries.

Example from my `Sensors.h` file:

```
#ifdef IR_SENSOR_USED
  #include "SparkFun_GridEYE_AMG88/src/SparkFun_GridEYE_Arduino_Library.h"
  extern GridEYE grideye;
  void setup_ir_sensor();
  void read_ir_sensor();
  void enable_ir_interrupt(float lower, float upper, float hysteresis);
  void disable_ir_interrupt();
#endif
```

and from my `Sensors.cpp` file:

```
#ifdef IR_SENSOR_USED
void setup_ir_sensor() {
  Wire.begin(16, 17, 0x69);
  grideye.begin(0x69, Wire);
}

void read_ir_sensor() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 64; i++) {
    sensor_values.ir_pixel_temp[i] = grideye.getPixelTemperature(i);
  }
  sensor_values.ir_device_temp = grideye.getDeviceTemperature();
}

void enable_ir_interrupt(float lower, float upper, float hysteresis) {...}

void disable_ir_interrupt() {...}
#endif
```

However, so long as I have the `#ifdef` in the .cpp file, I get the following error if I try to call the function in the `setup()`:

```
sketch/Sensors.ino.cpp.o:(.literal._Z5setupv+0xc): undefined reference to `read_ir_sensor()'
sketch/Sensors.ino.cpp.o: In function `setup()':
.../Sensors/Sensors.ino:112: undefined reference to `read_ir_sensor()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
```

If I comment them out, the code executes fine. Another function (`setup_sensors()`), which is also in the `Sensors.h` and `.cpp` files and is not surrounded by an `#ifdef` works also fine.

This is my `Sensors.ino` sketch:

```
#define IR_SENSOR_USED
//#define COLOR_SENSOR_USED
//#define ENV_SENSOR_USED
//#define TEMP_SENSOR_USED

#include "Sensors.h"

void setup() {
  sensor_setup();

  read_ir_sensor();
}

void loop() {
}
```

What's the reason for this? (Why) does the preprocessor not execute the directives in the .cpp file properly?

Comment: You do build with `Sensors.cpp` (or the object file created from it)? And the macro `IR_SENSOR_USED` *is* defined for all source files?

Comment: Where is `#define IR_SENSOR_USED` located?

Comment: In my `Sensors.ino`, I have `#define IR_SENSOR_USED` as the first line, before I have `#include "Sensors.h"`

Comment: So it's not defined when you build `Sensors.cpp`? Remember that your source files are built *separately* and that preprocessor directives (like macro definitions) are only for *single [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))*.

Comment: Is it not then? I assumed this would work. If it doesn't then, my entire approach is somewhat useless, isn't it? How else could I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't know the Arduino IDE system, but usually in an IDE one could set preprocessor macros in the project settings, and the macros will be defined for all source files in the project.

Comment: I'll look into that. Meanwhile, is there another approach I could use?

Comment: You could store your defines in a separate .h file and include it from `Sensors.h`. Another option is to have a define for the whole project via project settings. I don't know how exactly this is done for Arduino projects.

Comment: Hmm, I'd like to keep it as simple as possible (so also to only one file that the students would have to edit and deal with)

Comment: I've found this post, but I don't really understand what is done here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393975/how-to-globally-define-a-preprocessor-variable

Comment: Perhaps you could put your defines into a Makefile, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136904/how-can-i-define-define-in-my-make-files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments and other answer pointed out, any `#define` directives are only visible in the files that contain them. So having

```
#define IR_SENSOR_USED
```

in `Sensors.cpp` won't affect any code that's not compiled in `Sensors.cpp` (importantly, it will affect code that's contained in `.h` files that are included in `Sensors.cpp` after the `#define`. But it wouldn't affect anything contained in a different `.cpp` file.

More sophisticated build environments than Arduino have better and more complicated ways to deal with this problem, but the Arduino world doesn't give you a lot of tools to handle this.

What I do in the Arduino world is simply have a file called `config.h` which contains all the `#define` statements that I need project-wide. I `#include "config.h"` in each file that needs these values.

So in your case, you'd put your all the defines that show which devices are used in `config.h` and then `#include "config.h"` at the start of every file that depends on it.

You could even include it at the start of your `Sensors.h` file. I'd consider keeping the two files separate so that there would be a clear boundary between the stuff that needs to be configured and the stuff that's useful code.

I also keep any sensitive values (wifi credentials, passwords, API keys) in this file, and exclude it from code I publish on Github. In its place I include a "config-example.h" file with all the directives in it but with dummy values, so that others using the code can edit and rename it.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be an instance of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

If you would like the users of library to pick the functionality they need it would make more sense to put declarations in separate headers. E.g., `IR_sensor.h` and then

```
#define IR_SENSOR_USED
#include "Sensors.h"
```

becomes just `#include "IR_sensor.h"`.

- If the size of the library is or concern, splitting it into separate libraries is an option.
- The third option is to provide the functionality as a [header-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only) library.

**Exact answer:**

> What's the reason for this? (Why) does the preprocessor not execute
>   the directives in the .cpp file properly?

The most likely reason is that `Sensors.cpp` is unaware of `#define IR_SENSOR_USED`. Define is in another file that is not included.

However even if `IR_SENSOR_USED` would be defined in the `Sensors.cpp` another problem arises: re-compilation of `Sensors.cpp` for every possible combination of defines is necessary. Otherwise the ifdefed-code is excluded from compilation and can't be simply enabled on the client side by calling `#define`.